# Computer Slows to crawl after Event Id 3, some issue with Raid Port 0

Tags: windows-7, raid, freeze, crash, event-log

Recently my computer randomly hangs, crashes and slows down at night, when I click on something when I wake up the computer just doesn't respond and shows the loading thing for my cursor.

Today, I couldn't even boot up my computer. As soon as I logged in, the computer became unresponsive for 30 minutes in which I just forced the computer to shut down using the power button.

I can boot in Safemode with Networking, and I checked my Event Logs. Around the times that my computer has problems, there are many Event Id 3 error involving   `\Device\RaidPort0`  and occasions between those an error saying it's resetting RaidPort0. For these the sources was 'nvstor64'

I'm not sure whats wrong here.

Comment: This sounds like a bad hard drive. Do you have any strange noise coming from the hard drive?

Comment: My HD is completely silent

Comment: Rather strange, then.

Comment: hmm actually if I press my ear onto the case next to the harddrive I hear the spinning with a bit of humming, but nothing loud

Comment: Specifically, when this error happens (i.e. when the system slows down) does the HD make any clicking (or other non-normal) noise?

Comment: There's no noise from my HD when the problem occurs.

Comment: Then probably it's not an HD problem.

Comment: I don't think it's the HD, because safe mode words.. it's pretty much (mainly) the same thing as a normal boot.

Comment: @ArcaneExplosion I don't have the time or energy to right now, but I googled '\Device\RaidPort0 nvstor64' and apparently some other people had the same problem. You could probably find the answer on Google somewhere.

Comment: I've googled it and nothing helped, which I why I posted the question here.

Comment: Did you see this post? http://forums.nvidia.com/index.php?showtopic=166872